# Mobile fixed positioning footer (iOS6 [how does TechCrunch do it])?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios6

http://webdevout.net/test?0y3&raw

If you navigate to this link in IOS6 Safari and scroll the page, the element with fixed positioning scrolls with the page, and only snaps back to being fixed when you remove your finger. (if you don't get it the first time, refresh and try again)

The thing is... if you go to http://techcrunch.com on IOS6 and scroll, you won't get that at all ever. I don't seem to get exactly what they are doing for it to stay fixed in IOS6 that I'm not doing.

Comment: You could try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/WctNq/

Comment: @Chad That doesn't work. Too much added boilerplate. Besides, they aren't using that method. How are they accomplishing this without your method?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have iOS6 to specifically test, but I don't understand why they'd have a different experience for a specific version of OS, because I'm not seeing any fixed elements on their page at all.